# Is there any solution to observe a MutubleLiveData's state in View while it is changed through method's perameter in ViewModel

Tags: android, retrofit, mutablelivedata

MutableLiveData's state is not observed in Fragment while I pass a reference of its(MutableLiveData) instance through a method in ViewModel. Only http call is happened and value is shown in log, NO action corresponding LiveData's State is not observed

I want to call a Http method which logic is written in LoginViewModel which is a child class of BaseViewModel. In BaseViewModel I created some common methods which take MutableLiveData as parameter, call those method in LoginViewModel's method and observe those LiveData in Fragment

`UiState.kt`

```
sealed class UiState<T> {
    data class Progress<T>(val isLoading: Boolean) : UiState<T>()
    data class Success<T>(val successInfo: T) : UiState<T>()
    data class Failure<T>(val throwable: Throwable) : UiState<T>()
    data class Alert<T>(val alert: String) : UiState<T>()

    companion object {
        fun <T> loading(isLoading: Boolean): UiState<T> = Progress(isLoading)
        fun <T> success(successInfo: T): UiState<T>? = Success(successInfo)
        fun <T> failure(throwable: Throwable): UiState<T> = Failure(throwable)
        fun <T> alert(alert: String): UiState<T> = Alert(alert)
    }
}
```

`Event.kt`

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    private var hasBeenHandled = false

    fun getContentIfNotHandled() = if (hasBeenHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        content
    }

    fun peekContent() = content
}
```

`BaseViewModel.kt`

```
fun <T> onSuccessHttpResponse(state: MutableLiveData<Event<UiState<T>>>) = Consumer<Response<T>> {
    state.value = Event(loading(true))

    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        state.value = Event(loading(false))
        state.value = Event(success(it.body()!!)!!)
    } else {
        val error = Gson().fromJson(it.errorBody()?.charStream(), ApiError::class.java)

        when (it.code()) {
            Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_REFRESH_STATUS_CODE -> state.value = Event(alert("Renew Access Token please"))
            Constants.CUSTOM_STATUS_CODE -> state.value = Event(alert(error.message!!))
            else -> state.value = Event(alert("Something went wrong"))
        }

        state.value = Event(loading(false))
    }
}

fun <T> onErrorHttpResponse(state: MutableLiveData<Event<UiState<T>>>) = Consumer<Throwable> {
    state.value = Event(loading(false))
    state.value = Event(UiState.failure(it))
}

fun <T> inputNotFoundError(state: MutableLiveData<Event<UiState<T>>>) {
        state.value = Event(loading(false))
        state.value = Event(alert("Please Filled all Info"))
    }
```

`LoginViewModel.kt`

```
val tutorLoginState: MutableLiveData<Event<UiState<TutorLoginResponse>>> = MutableLiveData()

fun tutorLogin(loginInfo: LoginInfo) {
    if (loginInfo.isAssigned()) {
        callLoginTutorApi(loginInfo)
    } else {
        inputNotFoundError(tutorLoginState)
    }
}

private fun callLoginTutorApi(loginInfo: LoginInfo) {
    compositeDisposable += userLoginService.tutorLogin(loginInfo)
        .performOnBackgroundOutputOnMain()
        .subscribe({
            onSuccessHttpResponse(tutorLoginState)
        }, {
            onErrorHttpResponse(tutorLoginState)
        })
}
```

`LoginFragment.kt`

```
override fun observeLiveData() {
    viewModel.tutorLoginState.observe(this, Observer {
        it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { state ->
            when (state) {
                is UiState.Progress -> {
                    if (state.isLoading) {
                        network_loading_indicator.visible()
                    } else {
                        network_loading_indicator.visibilityGone()
                    }
                }

                is UiState.Success -> {
                    val responseData: TutorInfo = state.successInfo.data?.tutorInfo!!
                    context?.showToast(responseData.tutorName.toString())
                }

                is UiState.Alert -> context?.showToast(state.alert)

                is UiState.Failure -> {
                    if (state.throwable is IOException) {
                        context?.showToast("Internet Connection Failed")
                    } else {
                        context?.showToast("Json Parsing Error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Only Http call is happened. But no response in the change of LiveData

Comment: Did you try to debug? Please check whether your debug point is reaching 
till it.getContentIfNotHandled() or not. Start your debug from onSuccessHttpResponse()

Comment: @KishanMaurya yes, I debuged the method "onSuccessHttpResponse()". The method is called but LiveData's State was not changed. But if I write the code of onSuccessHttpResponse() and onErrorHttpResponse() directly in tutorLogin() method, the code run perfectly ok. But I don't want that. I want to separate those method in BaseViewModel Class.

Comment: May I know where your `inputNotFoundError()` method is? It's supposed to be in your `LoginViewModel`, as you've tried to design.

Comment: Also, what's the value of `tutorLoginState` when your `userLoginService.tutorLogin()` returns a success response? @Omi

Comment: @SaadAAkash brother, tutorLoginState value is not changed. That's why no response is called. Log is seen as I use interceptor in retrofit

Comment: You're missing the point here, you are trying to debug a Livedata which is dependign on `Event<UiState<TutorLoginResponse>>`, which is in your ViewModel, `tutorLoginState`. If I'm not wrong you're then trying to use it toggling the visibility of `network_loading_indicator` in your fragment. You could easily use doOnTerminate(), doOnSubscribe() and toggle a LiveData value of this loader from the respective ViewModel. Observe that livedata from your Activty/Fragment and just implement your UI logic of loader. You don't need UIStates and Events if you're using Architecture Components like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the prior conversation, you can handle the disposables in your BaseViewModel like this and create a LiveData value `loader` to handle it centrally inside the base and also, to reuse the same single live event in every API call & a `message` to show error in Toast or handle like this:

`BaseViewModel`

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    protected val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    val loader: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy { SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>() }
    val message: MutableLiveData<Message> by lazy { SingleLiveEvent<Message>() }
    override fun onCleared() {
        compositeDisposable.clear()
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel, keep a LiveData for the response and a disposable of it. Just toggle the `loader` value here so that it can be observed from the Fragment/Activity to toggle the loader visibility by using `doOnSubscribe()` and `doOnTerminate()` like the following (a detail explanation into using this RxJava action operators can found [here](https://medium.com/@ValCanBuild/making-rxjava-code-tidier-with-doonsubscribe-and-dofinally-3748f223d32d)). Basically to sum it up:

- `doOnSubscribe()` — Modifies the source so that it invokes the given action when it is subscribed from its subscribers.
- `doOnTerminate()` — Calls the specified action just before this Observable signals onError or onCompleted.

`LoginViewModel`

```
private lateinit var disposableResponse: Disposable
val tutorLoginResponse = MutableLiveData<TutorLoginResponse>()

fun login() {
       disposableResponse = userLoginService.tutorLogin()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { loader.value = true }
            .doOnTerminate { loader.value = false }
            .subscribe({
                    onRetrieveResponseSuccess(it)
                }, {
                    onRetrieveResponseError(it)
                })

        compositeDisposable.add(disposableResponse)
    }

private fun onRetrievePostListSuccess(response: TutorLoginResponse) {
        tutorLoginResponse.value = response
}

private fun onRetrievePostListError(error: Throwable) {
        message.value = ToastMessage(error.message) //ToastMessage is a simple utility class to show Toast
}
```

Then observe the updated LiveData value of `loader` from your viewmodel and toggle the visibility of your loader in UI from your Activity/Fragment & also access the response like this:

`LoginFragment`

```
viewModel.loader.observe(this, Observer {
            if(it) showLoader() //showLoader() is a simple method in BaseFragment which invokes .show() on your deafult or custom Lottie animated loader
            else hideLoader() //hideLoader() is a similar method for invoking .hide() on your loader
})

viewModel.tutorLoginResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
            //do whatever with your response that's been returned here
})
```

Comment: That's pretty clean code. But as per I know there is an issue in using SingleLiveEvent while using Navigation Component as I use Navigation Component in my Project. You can check this https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: Did you read the entire blog? Quoting "The problem with SingleLiveEvent is that it’s restricted to one observer. If you inadvertently add more than one, only one will be called and there’s no guarantee of which one." - how & more importantly, why would you require a loader to have more than one observer in the first place?!

Comment: vaia don't misunderstand me. SingleLiveEvent is best suited for your code here. But in my case, it failed ti fulfil the goal. That's why I said so

Comment: your code and this medium post help me to find the exact answer https://medium.com/@ValCanBuild/making-rxjava-code-tidier-with-doonsubscribe-and-dofinally-3748f223d32d
Thank a lot again vaia

Comment: Glad to know that @Omi. Please accept the answer too for the future users who may stumble upon a similar problem. I'm adding the link to this medium too exactly where it should explain my code even in more detail, i.e. my `LoginViewModel` codes.

Comment: I've added an explanation in detail again & linked the helpful resource & a short summary too of the aforementioned RxJava 2 action operators @Omi. Please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows, should change the color in green. I'd appreciate it.